# Can I save my damaged Aloe vera plant?

Tags: indoors, aloe, cuttings

I had an Aloe plant that had grown to about 10" tall, in the shape of a miniature Christmas tree. It was potted in a small 8" pot with two other succulents. Last night our cats broke the plant from the pot, leaving the roots in the pot and a small part of the stem. The plant is full and green.

Is there any chance of saving the plant or the roots or both?

Comment: could you please post a photo or two of the damaged plant?

Comment: Related: [Can we take out the whole root of aloe vera and replant it during transplant?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/504/) (see the answer)

Comment: My wife burns our aloe plant every year by putting outside in the spring without acclimating it. Every year it suffers 90%+ bleaching and death. However it rapidly sends up new leaves and is in good shape by winter - ready to do it all over again. I call it the resurrection plant. I'd love to hear how this turned out.

Answer (score 17):

Don't despair, fortunately aloes, like most succulents, root very readily. The best way forward is to (A) take a leaf cutting and (B) plant up the broken stem, as follows:

A.

- Remove a healthy leaf from the stem (with a sharp knife) and leave it to dry out for two or three days, until a thin 'skin' forms over the open edge;
- Insert it firmly in some moist potting soil, to a depth about one third of its length;
- Place the pot in a bright but sunless place;
- Water sparingly - keep the soil moist but *not wet*;

B.

- Repeat the last three steps using the broken stem, inserting it to a depth of 3-4".

Provided you don't over-water, your cuttings should take root by mid-September, and you will have two 'new' plants by next Spring.

Comment: will the roots be all right is there a possibility it will start growing again?

Comment: As the small piece of stem that is left in the pot has no leaves, I think this very unlikely; however, in addition to taking the steps I've suggested above, you could leave the roots in the pot and keep the soil slightly damp, to give it the best possible chance of surviving.

Comment: Aloe cannot be rooted from leaf cuttings. The bottom of this plant should make new growth, The stem (not the leaves) can be rooted. Aloe leaves lack a meristem which would allow new growth, both roots and leaves.