# Can an aloe plant that's completely rotten at the base be cured?

Tags: indoors, plant-health, aloe

I had a potted aloe plant that looked like a set of leaves coming out of a single spot at ground level. One day it just fell apart - the leaves and the roots got completely rotten at ground level and wouldn't hold leaves together and to the ground. Leaves otherwise look alive - they are just damaged at the end where they were connected to the root.

According to [this answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1566/can-i-save-my-damaged-aloe-vera-plant/1567#1567) aloe plant leaves can be planted on their own and can perhaps start growing as separate plants. Will that technique likely work in my rotten case? Do I have any other options?

Comment: Could you add some pictures? I know we ask this a lot, but most of time they are the only way we can actually diagnose what is going on in a certain situation. The chances of you getting a good answer go up astronomically if you post even a blurry picture (although good photography is encouraged).

Comment: My aloe plant has a little stalk under it before the leaves so it's the opposite case. It's under cover and I barely ever water it - perhaps 2-3 times a year - and it's doing just great. All I can suggest is that, being a succulent native to really arid regions, perhaps it's getting too MUCH water?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your leaves have rotted at the base, there is nothing practical you can do to save the plant. The leaves, though you can sometimes root them, would probably do poorly because they are not fresh. The best thing to do would be to find out what caused the rot, buy a new plant, and carefully monitor it so that you can fight the rot as soon as it appears.

Comment: I haven't tried leaf cuttings, but this is my experience too. Remove the leaves - sometimes enough of the core plant (or a side growth) might survive - but unlikely. Living in Texas, we had rot after severe (for us!) frosts.

Comment: @sharptooth I wouldn't give up on it yet. Our landlord entrusted us with an aloe that was his parents' plant. In the past 4 years, we've "killed" it a number of times in a number of ways, only to have the plant redeem us after we place a few of the green leaf tips (3-4"+) into the soil. They rooted and grew healthy new plants. Just make sure the base is clear of rotted material. I imagine some would say to let the cut air dry for a few days, but we didn't do this. Good luck.