# Will my Aloe vera plant survive after all of the leaves broke off?

Tags: plant-care, aloe

I have made the same mistake as the person who asked the question [Can I save my damaged Aloe vera plant?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1566/26): my *Aloe vera* plant fell off of its stand and all of the leaves bent and broke off except for a tiny new one on top. The stem didn't break though.

Will my Aloe survive? Will it grow new leaves again? How should I care for it at this point?

Answer (score 3):

Care for it normally.  It should grow leaves again given time, although some of them may grow out as side shoots from the main branch.

Comment: Should I remove the 2 long remaining leaves?

Comment: No, leave them.  Otherwise the plant won't have any way to make food to help it recover.