# How can I save these etiolated aloe crowns with under watered stems?

Tags: plant-care, propagation, aloe

Two succulent Aloe vera shoots easily fell off a friend's aloe plant from readjusting a pot. This plant is potentially under watered and, from looking at the main plant or by just observing the two crowns below, this plant is pretty etiolated and receives little sun.

[image]
  [image]
  [image]

Are these plants savable and what propagation method (plant as is-- stem propagation? division propagation) would be recommended?

I saw "[Can I save my damaged Aloe vera plant?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1566/can-i-save-my-damaged-aloe-vera-plant)" however I'm asking in regards to crowns whose stems may look a little dry. I'm not sure if the same actions would be taken regarding propagating these crowns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, I was in a similar situation a few weeks ago: A friend gave me an aloe crown that looked exactly like yours (i.e. slightly dry stem, no roots). What worked for me was to simply plant it into a pot with a mix of normal potting soil and some sand, water it and wait. It seems to have rooted quickly, at least it already started growing one or two new leaves.

I think an important point here is to avoid overwatering, or the plant would rot. The soil should be moist, but not too wet. I kept it in a rather warm and sunny spot near the window, but that most likely isn't necessary.

Comment: I went ahead and did this yesterday. Thanks

Comment: For reference: The plant is still doing fine and it even grew another stem. I was able to successfully divide the plant and grow another Aloe with this method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive, but I think you can just throw those in a glass of water and it will put out roots.

Comment: I've read somewhere that it's not great to propagate succulents in water.

Comment: If it's cut, and not dried out yet, no.  It will just rot.

Comment: Also that succulents like to pull moisture from soil and air, not particulary water.