# How do you save an aloe plant whose stem is weak and appears to be rotting?

Tags: plant-health, aloe

I have a large aloe plant that is probably 5 years old and has bloomed twice. Stem is very tall and leaves are approximately 2½ to 3ft (750 to 900mm) long and still very green except at the stem where they appear to be rotting. Also brown circular spots on some of the leaves. Very robust at the top however heavy and leaning over cannot support itself.

**Q.** How do I save this plant?

Comment: Can you please post a photo or two of the damaged plant?

Comment: Also take a look here: [Can we take out the whole root of Aloe Vera and replant it during transplant?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/504/394) & [Can I save my damaged Aloe-Vera plant](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1566/394)

Comment: Yes a photo will be useful. Are they rotting, or simply dying because they are old leaves?

Comment: I am new at this so bear with me here.  The plant is probably 5 yrs old and has bloomed twice. Stem is very tall and leaves are approximately 2½-3 ft long and still very green except @ the stem.  Also brown circular spots on some of the leaves.  Very robust at the top however heavy and leaning over cannot support itself.  I will try to post a picture, unfortunately a novice in that area too.

Comment: @Rennie Heads-up, I've moved the [above "comment" information](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2154/how-do-i-care-for-an-ailing-aloe-vera-plant#comment-3128) into [your question](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/2154/394). Please review & edit the actual question if need be...

Comment: @Rennie Did you have a read of the [above "linked" 2 SE questions?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2154/how-do-i-care-for-an-ailing-aloe-vera-plant#comment-3126) If yes, did they help or not?

Comment: Thank you, Mike Perry, for editing. I viewed: Can we take out the whole root of Aloe Vera and replant it during transplant? & Can I save my damaged Aloe-Vera plant. Interesting, though may not be helpful with my plant. Three large leaves have fallen off from rot.  How do I save this plant please?

Comment: @Rennie I'll echo what Winwaed and Mike have already said: A photo helps greatly! There are people here who are excellent at identifying issues/diseases from discolorations on the leaf. However, descriptions can only aid photos, not replace them. So please try to get hold of a picture as soon as you can.

Comment: @Yoda I understand and will do my best to post a picture as soon as I can.

Comment: You might want to describe the soil, and how you water it.

Comment: Is it getting enough light? When the soil touched the lowest leaves of my plants they started to rot. I usually mulch under mine so that the rain doesn't splash mud on the undersides of the leaves.

Comment: My success with aloe vera seems to be due to never (well, only once a year) watering it, and, being just under a verandah, it only gets small splashes of rain.

Answer (score 7):

Rotting in aloes is caused by fungus. The fungus enters through weak or dead growth, and spreads and grows when any of the following factors are present:

- Very high humidity
- Low light
- Too much water
- Poor drainage
- Extended low temperatures
- Extensive cuts or bruises
- Sitting water at the base of the leaves
- Sunburn (usually only in potted plants moved from low to full sun)
- Too much fertilizer

Prevention is better than cure. Try to provide the best conditions you can (ie, the opposite of the factors listed above). To control, apply a fungicide according to the directions on the label, until the infection is gone. Reapply at any sign of recurrence.

I had some problems with rot in my potted aloes, until I repotted them into a lighter mix.