# Is this aloe vera root rot?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, aloe, rot

Can someone verify if this is root rot on my aloe vera? It was starting to wilt so I had to re-pot. There were more root "hairs" but they were slimy and black and most of them stayed with the old dirt.

*Click on pictures for full size.*

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This is similar to [another thread](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2154/how-do-you-save-an-aloe-plant-whose-stem-is-weak-and-appears-to-be-rotting?rq=1) which has a more detailed answer to this question.

My aloe plant displayed the same symptoms when it was potted in a regular potting soil. When I replaced that soil with play sand with just a few clumps of manure the problem disappeared. I didn't need to apply any medicine to the plant, and it is now over 10 years old.

The roots grew back as soon as the moisture level dropped. To give you an idea how dry the soil should be, in one area that aloe is grown commercially typical rainfall is about 4 days a year. Regular, peat based, potting soil is just not dry enough.