# How should we treat cracks in the stem of Aloe Veras?

Tags: plant-care, succulents, aloe, damage, repair

I received this damaged Aloe Vera about 5 days ago and I found help, here mainly, to determine the source of its problems. So everything was on track now, until I realized that it had  soil in between its leaves that I couldn't remove and I had the "smart" idea of using an air compressed can to clean it -pressing it half way. It worked like a charm with the first leaf. With the second I may have pressed pass beyond the half way and the whole burst of air did what it is supposed to do. You can imagine the whole soil explosion scene and the cleaning chore it led to.

The real problem, though, is that it blew up more than the soil itself. The leaves have been damaged down at the root level. See the vertical crack in the white part of the plant that circled the left and right leaves:

[image]

Also, I have realized that it already had a horizontal crack in the leaf/steam inside and above the part already mentioned that you can see clearer in this pic:

[image]

Seen the images and that I have just repotted it 3 days ago into a pot filled with special-for-cactus soil, do you think it can still be repaired? And if yes -hopefully- do I need to cut the two outer leaves (and then can I replant them)? Or what should I do?

More pics of it made 4 days ago - before repotting it: 
[Causes of pale-brown tips](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24457/pest-etiolation-soil-or-overwatering-other-causes-of-pale-brown-tips-in-aloe?noredirect=1#comment29844_24457)

Update (May 9): 
The two bottom leaves are rotting at the stem, one of them has already fallen down -it is just supported by the pot- and the other is becoming brown at the stem so it will too... Is it better to remove the rest of the corresponding layer of stem (is a white part...)?

[image]

[image]

[image]

May 10, the leave in worst condition collapsed:

[image]

May 15, the entire plant collapsed. It stayed up for a couple of days after propelling it with a stick, but it seems it has definitively collapsed today and the stem is almost flat at the base, where the plant bent: 
[image]
[image]
[image]

I guess at this point there's nothing to be done... (?)

Comment: The Aloe is not getting pretty... no ideas about what can it be done?

Comment: You should put some aloe on it, it can help heal dried cracked skin!

Comment: You mean putting some aloe "cream" from one leaf over the dried stem skin? Actually, it looks as if it is not only the skin that it is dried...

Comment: sorry, no I was just making a joke about using aloe, considering it IS an aloe, I wouldn't expect any real affect

Comment: :) no problemo, it was just a little risky/rude to ask if it was a joke (in case it wasn't...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Aloe vera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloe_vera) is a succulent that has naturalized across the world from China to North and South America.  It "requires well-drained, sandy potting soil and bright, sunny conditions".

We have a few [questions](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=aloe) here about [watering](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/22266/is-this-aloe-vera-root-rot) and [soil mix](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/14676/499) that are relevant.

This plant has root rot brought on by too much water in a soil that has too much organic matter for this kind of plant. It is possible to save it by starting an offset or cutting but unlikely as the rot is advanced. Seeing as they are commonly available why not try another in a soil with more grit/sand/perlite and a location with more light and less water

Comment: The pot contains special soil for cactus, I've been very careful with light and well, you can see in my previous posts, mainly this: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24457/pest-etiolation-soil-or-overwatering-other-causes-of-pale-brown-tips-in-aloe , that I tried to save it from overwatering and other issues... But yes, I was trying to save this friend's plant and learn a bit about plants along the way, but I may have to get a new one... Yet, I'll even try starting an offset or cutting. Seeing the pics, do you know where should I cut it? I'll look for info on offsetting anyway...

Comment: @Martec  If the soil is right then then there is not enough light or too much water or both.  I don't think you can take a cutting if there is only the one stem.

Comment: Ok, so it seems the only viable "solution" left is just getting another one...

Comment: Indeed the stem is totally dead, to the point of the only thing that joins it with the root is mere skin...

Answer (score 5):

Succulents do not 'heal' in the traditional sense from cracks or tears. Leave it be, unless it is starting to rot, and hopefully the plant will continue to grow and a new leaf will come up. You could trim the damaged leaf at the stem, but this is not necessary and will just turn brown.

Comment: I see, so is it better to trim it or to leave as it is? It is not that I want to trim it for no purpose... The leave is actually already going to fall so, in any case, would I need to remove the rest of the stem?

Comment: Perhaps leave it for now and see how it goes. It might not die back.

Answer (score 5):

I would just leave it. This happens in the wild and plants are fine. It looks like a fairly new/small plant so pruning that much leaf structure might do more harm than good. If it's lacking support or if the leaf is pulling apart because of it's own weight then you could prop it up or tie a string around the plant to keep the leaves from falling.

Comment: I think it has died, the entire plant collapsed, I propelled it with a stick and seemed to be restoring but then it has falled again and the stem is almost flat at the juncture or the part that bent...

Comment: Judging by the look of the base of the stem that has new growth: it looks like you are correct and your plant is dying a slow death. Womp womp. It might still be possible to save it, but unlikely. I would try burying it a little more so that the white part of the good stem is covered with soil. The pot also looks a little dry. I know cacti don't need much water, but I would do anything I could to aid nutrient transfer to the good stem. Don't prune at all to avoid stress and let it sit how it grows. Give it LOTS of sun (but not to the point where it gets overly hot and burns).