# Can I save Aloe vera plants that were pulled out of the ground?

Tags: succulents, transplanting, aloe

Our new place has lots of different species of cacti plus Aloe vera plants. This entire walkway is way overgrown with Aloe vera. My grandson thought he was helping me by pulling a whole bunch out. Can I save all those he pulled?

[image]

Comment: Can you send me one???  I am kidding of course!!

Comment: Looks like 100% of what I see is viable. These are hard to kill.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Aloe plants are extremely tough. They can easily survive being out of the ground for a few weeks. As long as they are still green and have not completely dried out or rotted they can still be planted.

Judging by the picture I would say that you can still plant most of these Aloes without a worry.

See the answer at: [Can we take out the whole root of Aloe Vera and replant it during transplant?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/504/can-we-take-out-the-whole-root-of-aloe-vera-and-replant-it-during-transplant)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen aloe Vera survive a year out of the ground. No soil no food no water. Still survived.